# Keycloak session doesn't expire

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I have a Spring MVC web app with Spring Security using Keycloak v24.0.2 and Spring Boot v3.2.4. In Keycloak I set up parameters "SSO Session Idle" and "Access Token Lifespan" to 1 minute, but a session still doesn't expire after user being idle during 1 minute. I expect redirection to login screen after being idle this time. What is wrong with my setting? Below is my configuration.

*build.gradle*

```kotlin
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client'
    ...
}
```

*application.yaml*

```yaml
...
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          keycloak:
            client-id: local-client
            client-secret: [my-client-secret]
            scope: openid
        provider:
          keycloak:
            issuer-uri: http://localhost:8180/realms/local-realm
            user-name-attribute: preferred_username
...
```

*MySecurityConfig.java*

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MySecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                .anyRequest()
                .fullyAuthenticated())
            .oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .logout(logout -> logout
                .logoutSuccessHandler(oidcLogoutSuccessHandler())
                .permitAll());
        return http.build();
    }
    OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler oidcLogoutSuccessHandler() {
        OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler successHandler =
            new OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler(clientRegistrationRepository);
        successHandler.setPostLogoutRedirectUri("{baseUrl}");
        return successHandler;
    }
}
```

*Keycloak > local-realm > Realm settings > Sessions*
[image]

*Keycloak > local-realm > Realm settings > Tokens*
[image]

Comment: There are two sessions, one for Keycloak used to login and one of your application. If your application's session is still valid there is no need to login again. You are not using your access token after logging in, so no relogin is neccessary.